# Microsoft reporting services report taking too much time with huge data

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using Microsoft SQL reporting for reporting but facing problem because I have huge amount of data, from huge i mean 100000 to 1000000 records. When i retrieve records it joins 8 tables, So I want to know is Microsoft reporting is feasible with this amount of data as i have read articles that it slow downs performance or is there any other option like Crystal Reports or any other component?

My query is in a stored procedure and i fill that in a DataSet.xsd and then use it on my page using ObjectDataSource to bind it with report.
Another thing is I have to use charts component as well in reporting.
Im using Sql server 2008 R2 standard version with Asp.Net 4 application.

Comment: How long does the query take? Also, is someone actually going to read all 1000000 rows? If not, then you should filter the rows to be closer to what is required.

Comment: I wait almost 5minutes and it doesn't generating the report and yes user can select a criteria to view all records.

Comment: I asked how long the query takes, not how long the report takes. Maybe it's simply a query that takes a long time to run.

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt your users are looking at 1 million or even 100k records - and you mention the chart control as well.  If you are needing to give them flexible aggregations, consider adding SQL Server Analysis Services to your reporting server and building a cube from your online data.  An Excel add-in can be used to crunch numbers - it's pretty slick.

Perhaps you need to build more reports and procedures that do specific filtering or aggregation.  Creating reports with that many rows is going to cause problems.

If you could explain what your users do with all that data, maybe there could be a better answer.

Comment: I agree with you. Analysis services could help A LOT as datasource

Answer (score 0):

You can run the query below to find out:

```
SELECT Name, TimeDataRetrieval,TimeProcessing,TimeRendering
    , TimeDataRetrieval+TimeProcessing+TimeRendering AS TotalTime,Format,Parameters,username,TimeStart
FROM dbo.ExecutionLog L WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN dbo.Catalog R WITH (NOLOCK) ON L.ReportID = R.ItemID
WHERE Name='' -- update parameters for report name
AND Format>'' 
ORDER BY Name
```

TimeDataRetrieval is how long the query takes to execute.

Try to run the same query from Management Studio on the same client and compare the execution time of both.